# "it tore from the wall"

Tags: phrase-usage

> He lunged for the nearest painting he could see, a Caravaggio. Grabbing the gilded frame, the seventy-six-year-old man heaved the masterpiece toward himself until ***it tore from the wall*** and Sauniere collapsed backward in a heap beneath the canvas.
>
> <sub>The Da Vinci Code</sub>

I don't understand the clause "it tore from the wall" here. According to dictionaries, the usage is "tear sth. from sth.". So, "*it was torn from the wall*" looks right to me. I can be wrong as it's been written in the book like that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: the verb may be intransitive too = to separate on being pulled : _this cloth tears easily_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the entry from the [Cambdridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tear) for **tear**

> tear verb (PULL APART)
>
> B1 [ I or T ]
>   to pull or be pulled apart, or to pull pieces off

Note the **I or T** there... it means that the verb can be transitive "she tore the dress" or intransitive "the dress tore".

It is therefore perfectly OK grammatically to say "it tore from the wall". It doesn't sound like a very natural way of describing what happened, but it would be difficult to do better without using a lot of words, and that would reduce the dramatic impact.

Answer (score 2):

You're right it sounds clumsy (imo) but it's not technically incorrect - tear can be an intransitive verb (no direct object) so, for example, "the cloth tore from top to bottom" is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that painting is glued the the wall with super glue. You can't just take it off the wall like if it was hanging from a single nail with a string. You have to pull the painting out *very hard*, possibly tearing/ripping/damaging the painting in the process.

When you "tear the painting from the wall", you pull it off the wall very hard and/or violently.